# Sinon Not Mocking db-mysql Node.js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to mock my database using Sinon with Mocha in Node.js for testing. I've tried the following:

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var mysql = require('db-mysql');

beforeEach(function() {
  var db = sinon.mock(mysql);
  db.expects('execute');
});
```

but I keep getting the following error: `TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property execute as function`

I assumed that this is mocking the class and not the database instance. So I mocked the instance by doing `var db = sinon.mock(new mysql.Database());` instead. When I did that, then all the valid methods for the `db-mysql` instance are passing, such as `db.connect()` and `db.query()`, no matter what the arguments are. I am unable to set behaviour. To set the behaviour, I am trying to call `.expects` on `db` but I get the following error:

`TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'expects'`

What's the right way to set the expected behaviour? Furthermore, how can I test several behaviours for the same function? Will I need to do this within each test according to what the test expects?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `execute` is part of `query` object and not the database itself.

https://github.com/mariano/node-db-mysql#quick-start

Comment: How do you stub out the query object in the database object, so you can run a stubbed out execute?

Comment: `sinon.stub(db.query, "execute");` maybe?